Export subpath for a react-native library
i m trying to create a react-native library which export some components and utilities. I'd like to be able to import my code like this :
import { RandomComponent } from 'mylibrary';
import { otherstuff } from 'mylibrary/otherstuff'

Btw, i used create-react-native-library to setup my project.
I've seen the following Question which is quite similar, but i can't manage to get it work. My project contains 2 package.json :
/A/package.json
/A/B/package.json

A contains react-native component and utilities
B contains a react-native expo app to test A
In my 'A/package.json' i have :
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./lib/typescript/src/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./lib/module/index.js",
      "require": "./lib/commonjs/index.js"
    },
    "./theme": {
      "types": "./lib/typescript/src/theme.d.ts",
      "import": "./lib/module/theme.js",
      "require": "./lib/commonjs/theme.js"
    }
  },

And i've set in my 'A/B/tsconfig.json':
"compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "bundler" 
  }

When importing my library in B like this, it works
import { RandomComponent} from 'mcomponents';

but when importing like this, it looks like it doesn't even exist
import { otherstuff} from 'mcomponents/theme';

